# Is SSH root login without password and without copying public key possible?

Tags: server, ssh, login, password

I'd like to configure sshd_config to allow remote root logins without prompting for a password, but I do not want to configure passwordless ssh by copying the remote public key. In other words, I'd like to allow ssh root@host from anywhere without a password prompt. Is this possible to accomplish?

Thanks!

Some more info:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
```

```
# passwd --delete root
# service ssh restart
```

```
sh@sh-desktop:~$ su - root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure

sh@sh-desktop:~$ ssh -vvv root@localhost
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I also tried to set UsePAM no, but than I cannot login at all. Perhaps something needs to be done in PAM config.

Comment: I don't need any security for this one. It's not connected to any public network. So yes, anyone should be able to take over the system.

Comment: You need to explain why. Why don't you want to install the public key? SSH keys have been designed to accomplish exactly that you don't need to type a password. Also, there is a reason `root` access is not normally enabled - it would be a huge security hole if you do what you propose. Please explain your rationale and your security considerations for this.

Comment: *"I don't need any security for this one."* Sounds like famous last words to me ...

Comment: Sorry, either you know if it's possible with SSH or you don't, but explaining the rationale behind it won't make a difference. Exchanging the public key would simply be an unnecessary nuisance for no good reason. There are no security concerns for this particular machine whatsoever. Please believe me.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll never understand why exchanging the public keys will be any more difficult than changing the config files to put the server into a more unsecure state. But of course you do what you want to do with your server. Good luck! 

Comment: I'm doing a special purpose installation and may share the disk image it with some friends. There's no need for any password.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I don't reckon any supported version that has `OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` - is it Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Yes, it's old, and no need to upgrade. It's just to run a specific diagnostic tool for a specific piece of hardware, running low level tests that may not work on something newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the following was required, in addition to the mentioned parameters in sshd_config.

edit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
change nullok_secure to nullok

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
```

For example:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64)

$ ssh sh@192.168.2.101
sh@192.168.2.101's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64)


ssh root@192.168.2.101
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64)
```

The meaning of `nullok_secure` is documented in [the older version of the pam_unix man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_unix.8.html). In [Ubuntu 22](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/pam_unix.8.html) the option `nullok_secure` got removed.

Comment: Btw, nullok_secure does the same thing as long as the value
of PAM_TTY is set to one of the values found in /etc/securetty. In my case, nullok is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to log in as `root` via `ssh`, you need to adjust the configuration of your SSH-Daemon (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).

```
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

To activate your configuration changes, you can restart the daemon with:

```
systemctl restart ssh
```

This only works if the user `root` has no password. You can remove root's password with:

```
passwd --delete root
```

Edit 1: You need to prefix these commands with `sudo`, if you aren't already logged in as `root`.

Edit 2: All these changes need to be made on the server side only, nothing on the client side.

Comment: Apparently this alone isn't the solution. I was going to provide some more info, but the comment section doesn't allow me to post code or newlines.